# Слово с -не-

Tags: грамматика

Пока почти не исследованная разновидность аргументации — верно ли написано слово с -не-?

Answer (score 2):

Соглашусь, что надо писать раздельно. Здесь надо обратить внимание на два момента. Первое - наречие меры и степени *почти* не влияет на раздельное написание, *почти неисследованная* надо писать слитно. Но есть еще *пока*, которое, если это наречие, влияет на раздельное написание НЕ с причастиями. ПО правилу, если встречаются оба условия, выбираем раздельное написание.

Но контекста не хватает!!! Потому что если *пока* будет союзом, тогда писать надо слитно.

Comment: >>> почти неисследованная надо писать слитно  
Не согласен. Если только в каком-то особом контексте. Но я даже его не вижу. А так - нет причин. Что за качество такое "неисследованность"?  
Почти невидимая, почти незначимая - ещё можно представить. Но не более того.

Comment: Так гласит правило: если в качестве пояснительных слов при причастии выступают количественные наречия (наречия меры и степени) почти, отчасти, довольно, гораздо, вполне, полностью, очень, абсолютно, совершенно и др., то НЕ с причастием пишется слитно.

Comment: То, что вы имеете в виду, это не правило, а назидание для нерадивых учеников. Может быть полезным или нет, но никогда не будет императивным критерием, максимум - статистическим.
 
Правило - настоящее - одно. Раздельно, если отрицаение, слитно если новое качество. Из этого и исхожу.

Comment: Раздельно, если отрицание, слитно если новое качество - это для прилагательных, существительных и наречий. НЕ для причастий. И с каких это пор орфографические правила только для учеников?

Comment: Мы (все)здесь на вопросы по-разному отвечаем. То в соответствии с правилами и грамматиками, то в соответствии со своим языковым чутьем.  Я думаю, выбирать точку обзора надо исходя из вопроса. Автора интересует строгая норма, зафиксированная словарями и справочниками, или ему интересно порассуждать о разных вариантах и точках зрения. Иногда модератор напоминает, что дискуссии здесь не предусмотрены, но мы все равно обсуждаем и спорим... Может, какую-нибудь ветку отдельную создать для любителей не спрашивать, а отвечать? С уважением ко всем знающим и думающим.

Answer (score 0):

Причастие при наличии зависимых слов пишется раздельно. (Если, конечно, без НЕ не употребляется)

Разве "почти" - это не наречие? Которое и является зависимым словом?

Comment: И какие слова тут зависимые?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь, наверное, раздельно.
"почти неисследованная" произаодит очень странное впечатление. Оно не означает "очень мало исследованная", а что-то наподобие "почти стала неисследованной".
Вообще с "почти" - почти всегда раздельно, не сочтите за каламбур.  
Хотя обычно наречия к пресловутым "зависимым словам" не относят.